Apache Nifi PublishKafka Retry Mechanism in case of failure
I want to do error handling of publish kafka processor in case of kafka goes down in apache nifi by retry mechanism.
Retry mechanism needs to be implemented in separate flow(remove load from main flow).
Nifi version = 1.18.0
So, in case of failure of publishKafka processor should pass flow file in the failure relationship. Which is working properly in case of low count of incoming flow files.
Example-
Initial image
generated few flow files for failure case
https://i.sstatic.net/itdpEwVj.png
Final image after some time
Flow files successfully directed to failure relationship
https://i.sstatic.net/XWtMKUYc.png
As the number of incoming flow files increases the flow files are not able to routed to the failure relationship by publishKafka processor.(which is the real life scenario, if kafka goes down then publishKafka processor will apply back pressure to incoming flow files.)
Here is my publishKafka processor configs
Link for image of kakfa configs
I tried using inbuilt retry mechanism of nifi processor
(https://i.sstatic.net/TGynmzJj.png)
But still the issue is not resolved, publish kafka processor not forwarding flow files in failure relationship in case of error.

Since you are saying the flow files are not getting routed if the incoming flow file increases I would suggest you to increase the backpressure threshold size of the queue. Can you provide the more detail about the queue in which backpressure is getting applied ? The details in the question are minimal.
